# Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using an onClick function and trying to also pass an object with it. I need the object to make the function work. But for some reason it is giving me this error.

The error is coming from the onClick function from the delete button that I am rendering on each comment. If I remove the comment I am passing with it the error goes away (so the function itself is not the problem). I am not sure if I am passing the comment through wrong or what.

As I usually do if you request more information or want me to try to console log something I will put it in an edit so the comments do not get crowded and it will be easier for others to see.

```
    renderCommentsButtons(comment) {
    const { post, user, auth } = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id) {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={this.deleteComment, comment}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
              Delete
            </button>
            <Link
              to={`/posts/${post._id}/comments/${comment._id}/edit`}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              Edit
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }

  renderComments() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    return post.comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={comment._id}>
          <div>
            {comment.text} : {comment.author.email}
          </div>
          {this.renderCommentsButtons(comment)}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  deleteComment({ author, _id}) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    const {user} = this.props;

    if(this.props.auth) {
      if(user._id === author.id){
        this.props.deleteComments(id, _id, () => {
          this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button
  onClick={() => this.deleteComment(comment)}
  className="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
  Delete
</button>
```

You are not passing the comment in correctly, `onClick` takes a function only, if you want to pass parameters you must do it like above.

Comment: That caused it to work! How come I cant just pass it through like I did? I have done that before and it has worked just fine.

Comment: @TaylorAustin You're mistaken. You've never done it like this before because react event handlers only take one parameter, a function to call when the event happens. If you can find that example I could show why it is different

Comment: I am mistaken sorry, could you help out with this problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891664/trying-to-delete-comments-and-end-up-deleting-post-and-not-comment-using-react-n