# Trying to delete comments and end up deleting post and not comment using REACT/NODE/EXPRESS/MONGODB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

The problem here is that I am trying to delete a comment and instead it deletes the post it belongs too. I have checked to make sure I am not calling the wrong function somewhere, but I can't seem to find that I am. I am not sure if this is wrong coding on the front or back-end.

I will separate the code from server and client and also try to make it clear what does what. I am using react for front side and node/express/mongodb for my back-end.

As I usually do if you request more information or want me to try to console log something I will put it in an edit so the comments do not get crowded and it will be easier for others to see.

**Edit:** Added posts reducer and comments reducer.

**Client:**

**Comment show page:**

I am pressing the delete button which calls an `onClick` event handler that calls the deleteComment function. I have console logged all the information inside the function to make sure everything is what I want it to be.

```
renderCommentsButtons(comment) {
    const { post, user, auth } = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id) {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              onClick={() => this.deleteComment(comment)}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
              Delete
            </button>
            <Link
              to={`/posts/${post._id}/comments/${comment._id}/edit`}
              className="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              Edit
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }

  renderComments() {
    const { post } = this.props;

    return post.comments.map((comment) => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={comment._id}>
          <div>
            {comment.text} : {comment.author.email}
          </div>
          {this.renderCommentsButtons(comment)}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  deleteComment(comment) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    const {user, post, auth} = this.props;

    if(!user) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }

    if(auth) {
      if(user._id === comment.author.id){
        this.props.deleteComments(id, comment._id, () => {
          this.props.history.push(`/posts/${post._id}`);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Action for deleteComment:**

I have logged everything here as well. Everything is being passed through correctly as you can see.

```
export function deleteComments(post_id, comment_id, cb) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log('post_id:', post_id, 'comment_id:', comment_id);
    axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${post_id}/comments/${comment_id}`)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: DELETE_COMMENTS,
          payload: comment_id
        });
      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

**Server:**

**Route:**

```
app.delete('/posts/:id/comments/:comment_id', requireAuth, Comments.deleteComment);
```

**Controller:**

```
exports.deleteComment = function(req, res, next) {
  Comments.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect(`/posts/${req.params.id}`)
    }
  })
}
```

**Comments Model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var commentSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        email: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("comments", commentSchema);
```

**Posts Model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    content: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        },
        email: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "comments"
        }
    ]
});

var Posts = mongoose.model("posts", postsSchema);

module.exports = Posts;
```

**How I populate the comments inside post:**

```
exports.getOnePost = function(req, res, next) {
  Posts.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPost) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(foundPost);
    }
  });
}
```

**Posts Reducer:**

```
import {
  GET_ALL_POSTS,
  GET_POST,
  CREATE_POST,
  DELETE_POST,
  UPDATE_POST
} from '../actions/types';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_POSTS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, '_id');
    break;
    case GET_POST:
      return {...state, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data};
    break;
    case DELETE_POST:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    break;
    case UPDATE_POST:
      let updates = {[action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data}
      return _.merge(...state, updates);
    break;
    default:
      return state;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Comments Reducer:**

```
import {
  GET_COMMENTS,
  CREATE_COMMENTS,
  DELETE_COMMENTS,
  UPDATE_COMMENTS
} from '../actions/types';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function(state={}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_COMMENTS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, '_id');
    break;
    case CREATE_COMMENTS:
      return {...state, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data};
    break;
    case DELETE_COMMENTS:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    break;
    case UPDATE_COMMENTS:
      let updates = {[action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data}
      return _.merge(...state, updates);
    break;
    default:
      return state;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the posts and comments reducer. show `findByIdAndRemove` as well. Can't see anything obvious here that could be causing it

Comment: They have been added and `findByIdAndRemove` is in there I believe under controller.

Comment: Check that the string for `DELETE_COMMENTS` is actually what you expect and not actually pointing to `DELETE_POST`.

You posted the controller, but not the `findByIdAndRemove` function that you call from the controller that is on `Comments`. Reducers look fine

Comment: If you look in the router that is where I am calling the function from the controller unless you are talking about the findByIdAndRemove itself which is a mongo function I believe. I just did not want to post an entire page of code when one line is really only needed. `DELETE_COMMENTS` is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I did a postman delete request just to make sure it wasn't the front end and it is still deleting the whole post. Not the comment. If I go to robomongo, the comment is in fact still there in the comments collections.